# How to use GraphQL without React?

Tags: graphql

I'm currently using GraphQL for my React application.

How can you use GraphQL for a multi-page website?

I'm guessing there would need to be some sort of initial page load to the browser which would send queries to the GraphQL server.

Comment: I don't clearly get your question but you would use it in the same way how you would access any other API. You can do a POST call to the GraphQL server endpoint with the query.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question, as this will help the community understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following points must be considered

- GraphQL is a set of specifications and can be implemented in any language.
- In simple terms graphql is an **LAYER** between your frontend and backend API's
- IF you need data from **multiple** web API's you just send a query to graphql server it will do the heavy lifting of hitting the API's and aggregating the result and send response to the client.
- Graphql query is nothing but simple http call to grahpql server asking to data which get resolved at graphql server.

Now coming to your question, you can use graphql irrespective of the frontend tech you use `React Angular jQuery etc`. It simple http request. If your page is multipage website you can load the static content form web server and for dynamic content you can use graphql query through ajax.

Comment: Thanks, so i would serve html from teh server but embed say for example Javascript into that html file? The client would then request for that Javascript file from the server and render on the browser?

Comment: Wha you will do is, as you said serve html from server, embed javascript file in that html file. Once the html file is loaded in the browser the javascript file will get loaded in the browser. Now in that javascript you can write ajax to send query to graphql and get the response from graphql and render in your html page.